# How to generate CSV raport for two models in one table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I have two models: **Company** and **Employer** with following attributes:

```
Company
  Name
  Phone
  Address
Employer
  Name
  Phone
  Address
```

I would like to generate CSV table like below:

[image]

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just do it in folded cycles

UPD: and as Yuriy sais one should use eager loading

```
companies = Company.includes(:employers).all
...
companies.each do |c|
  csv << c.info
  c.employers.each do |e|
    csv << e.info
  end
end
```

Comment: I suppose `Company.includes(:employers).all.each` will make it in two sql requests.

Comment: @YuriyGolobokov, yes, sure, one should use eager loading. but the Q is about csv.